# How to update attribute of selected features in ArcMap with a shortcut?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.3

I have to edit/move/create/delete a no of polygons based on their respective comparison with reality. For all the polygons that I've moved, I have to update a field called remark as "U". This is really annoying to switch everytime to the attribute window and update the same.

Is there any shortcut/add-in/extension that could enable this step in a single click(shortcut key) or automated if possible?

Liscence is Basic for ArcMap 10.3

Comment: You should explore Editor Tracking, it will record when and who updates a record. It is available with a Basic License, but your data must be in a File Geodatabase. Right-click the layer, properties, editor tracking, Enable editor tracking.

Comment: Try Results window to repeat field calculation.

Comment: Is your data in a database? A *real* database not file geodatabase? Real databases support trigger functions which may be of use. In ArcObjects there is an event IEditEvents.OnChangeFeature which will pass the feature as it is being changed, I have used this to automatically tag a feature with A for attribute change, S for geometry modified, B for both and N for new but beware the update fires another event so if you're not careful you can go into an infinite loop. If ArcObjects isn't your thing then Emil's answer is the way to go, open the python window and copy/paste the code each time.

Comment: Work on a copy. Compare when done and populate field in question at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use selection and Python. This may be faster. Make sure your edited feature is selected. Then use the below code in the Python window.

```
if arcpy.Describe ("layer").FIDSet:
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor ("layer", "update_field") as curs:
        for row in curs:
            row = ("U",)
            curs.updateRow (row)
else:
    print "no selection"
```

`"layer"` is the name of the layer you're updating. `"update_field"` is the field you're updating with a `U`. This process can be easily repeated because once the code is run you can move your cursor to the code and press `Enter` to run the code as many times as desired.

[image]